# Error while starting android emulator: FB::flushWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: window handle 0x4 not found

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just started working with android.
So when i try to start the AVD (details below) it doesn't start, just a black screen for a time, until I get tired of it and shut it down.
I have intelhaxm installed, and hyper-v disabled.

This is the log i got form the console:

```
[2014-07-28 20:02:52 - app2] ------------------------------
[2014-07-28 20:02:52 - app2] Android Launch!
[2014-07-28 20:02:52 - app2] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-28 20:02:52 - app2] Performing com.example.app2.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-07-28 20:02:52 - app2] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Test5' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2014-07-28 20:02:52 - app2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test5'
[2014-07-28 20:02:53 - Emulator] emulator: device fd:1152
[2014-07-28 20:02:53 - Emulator] 
[2014-07-28 20:02:53 - Emulator] HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
[2014-07-28 20:02:55 - Emulator] creating window 0 0 480 800
[2014-07-28 20:02:55 - app2] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-07-28 20:02:55 - app2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-07-28 20:03:00 - Emulator] FB::flushWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: window handle 0x4 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:00 - Emulator] FB: closeColorBuffer cb handle 0x3 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:06 - Emulator] FB::flushWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: window handle 0x8 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:06 - Emulator] FB: closeColorBuffer cb handle 0x7 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:11 - Emulator] FB::flushWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: window handle 0xc not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:11 - Emulator] FB: closeColorBuffer cb handle 0xb not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:16 - Emulator] FB::flushWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: window handle 0x10 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:16 - Emulator] FB: closeColorBuffer cb handle 0xf not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:21 - Emulator] FB::flushWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: window handle 0x14 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:21 - Emulator] FB: closeColorBuffer cb handle 0x13 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:26 - Emulator] FB::flushWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: window handle 0x18 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:26 - Emulator] FB: closeColorBuffer cb handle 0x17 not found
[2014-07-28 20:03:30 - Emulator] Error accepting connection, aborting!`
```

AVD specifications:

[image: AVD Specifications]

Comment: Try this with 'Use Host GPU' turned off in the emulator settings.  I had the same error and that fixed it.

Comment: why does that cause a problem?

Comment: but is still works pretty slow... even though i installed intel haxam

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's the deal.  Host GPU is only supported for AVD devices that are using API 15 or later.  You also have to have Android SDK Tools 17 or later installed.  Also Host GPU is experimental.  All of this is in the emulation documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Also your machine has to support OpenGL (most do) and you will get better results if your machine has a separate GPU even though it will work with integrated graphic chipsets as well.

If you cannot take advantage of Host GPU then use the Snapshot option instead to gain some performance boost.  This will take a snapshot of the ram on the initial start of the emulated device and then reuse it on initial boot start ups of the device.  (Snapshot and Host GPU are actually mutually exclusive even though the ADV allows you to check both.)