# Why can't I create an AVD for any other targets other than android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I've been trying to create an AVD 4.0 and I've selected  5.4'' FWVGA as the device.
When I select the target as 2.3.3 the AVD gets created successfully for any device. I've downloaded all the packages as well. When I select the device by default the target comes as 2.3.3.

Comment: Post a screen shot of your android SDK manager

Comment: @BlazeTama I'm new to stackoverflow so it doesn't allow me to post images. I have installed from API 10 to API 20 only.

Comment: You can use something like tinypic :) Btw please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you havent installed the `system image`, go toy our `SDK Manager` and check if you have installed the image of each SDK version.

And check this link :

[Error while starting android emulator: FB::flushWindowSurfaceColorBuffer: window handle 0x4 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000723/error-while-starting-emulator-emulator-fbflushwindowsurfacecolorbuffer-wind)

Comment: In API 14 I have installed System Image but in some I haven't installed MIPS System Image and Intel x86 Atom System Image. Should i install them as well?

Comment: @darsh123 no you just need 1 `system image` for each SDK to run the emulator. Post a pic of your problem when creating the emulator in the tinypic so we can take a look

Comment: <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=334hds1" target="_blank"><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/334hds1.png" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>

Comment: and yes I have installed at least one system image

Comment: @darsh123 so the screen will just be black?

Comment: @darsh123 see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000723/error-while-starting-emulator-emulator-fbflushwindowsurfacecolorbuffer-wind

Comment: I think i found the answer there @BlazeTama I just had to change the emulation options to SnapShot. I was using Host GPU. Thanks :)